# Metric on space of càdlàg functions

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I want to ask some problem in Protter's book
Let $\mathbb{D}$ and $\mathbb{L}$ denote the set of adapted process with càdlàg paths, and the set of adapted process with càglàd paths, respectively.

[image]

1. Can we denote $H_t^* := \sup_{0 \le s \le t} |H_s|$ on $\mathbb{L}$, because càglàd function $[0,t]$ can be unbounded?
2. Can we define a metric on $\mathbb{L}_{ucp}$?

Thanks for your help.